# Mvel iterate a list

Tags: java, expression, evaluation, mvel

I have this class hierarchy

**StudentClass .java**

```
public class StudentClass {

    private List<Student> studentList;

    public List<Student> getStudentList() {
        return studentList;
    }

    public void setStudentList(List<Student> studentList) {
        this.studentList = studentList;
    }
}
```

**Student.java**

```
public class Student {

    private Child child;

    private int   studAge;

    public Student(Child child, int studAge) {
        this.child = child;
        this.studAge = studAge;
    }

    public Child getChild() {
        return child;
    }

    public void setChild(Child child) {
        this.child = child;
    }

    public int getStudAge() {
        return studAge;
    }

    public void setStudAge(int studAge) {
        this.studAge = studAge;
    }

}
```

**Child.java**

```
public class Child {

    private String name;

    private int    age;

    public Child(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

**Main class**

Through some logic i build this expression to execute through `MVEL`. This piece of code **works fine when `child2` is null**, but when **`child1` is null it gives below error**.
This is a valid scenario, and it is just a replica of my entities from my application. Child might come as null inside Parent.

**Issue only comes when object is null at index 0 , rest all indexes it works fine, even if at index 1 it is null, and index 0 fails if condition, then it will execute at index 2**

```
public class MvelTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String s = "if(contextObjectStudentClass.?studentList != null ){ foreach ( loopVariable0 : contextObjectStudentClass.?studentList){if ( loopVariable0.?child.?age==21 ){return  loopVariable0.?child.?name ;}}}return null ;";

        Child child2 = new Child("ankur", 23);
        Child child1 = null;
        Child child3 = new Child("ankurs", 21);

        Student s1 = new Student(child1, 21);
        Student s2 = new Student(child2, 23);
        Student s3 = new Student(child3, 27);

        List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        studentList.add(s1);
        studentList.add(s2);
        studentList.add(s3);

        StudentClass class1 = new StudentClass();
        class1.setStudentList(studentList);

        Map map = new HashMap();
        map.put("contextObjectStudentClass", class1);

        System.out.println(MVEL.eval(s, map));

    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot invoke getter: getChild (see trace)
    at org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.nodes.GetterAccessor.getValue(GetterAccessor.java:70)
    at org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.nodes.VariableAccessor.getValue(VariableAccessor.java:37)
    at org.mvel2.optimizers.dynamic.DynamicGetAccessor.getValue(DynamicGetAccessor.java:73)
    at org.mvel2.ast.ASTNode.getReducedValueAccelerated(ASTNode.java:108)
    at org.mvel2.ast.BinaryOperation.getReducedValueAccelerated(BinaryOperation.java:114)
    at org.mvel2.compiler.ExecutableAccessor.getValue(ExecutableAccessor.java:38)
    at org.mvel2.ast.IfNode.getReducedValueAccelerated(IfNode.java:73)
    at org.mvel2.compiler.ExecutableAccessor.getValue(ExecutableAccessor.java:38)
    at org.mvel2.ast.ForEachNode.getReducedValue(ForEachNode.java:136)
    at org.mvel2.MVELInterpretedRuntime.parseAndExecuteInterpreted(MVELInterpretedRuntime.java:106)
    at org.mvel2.MVELInterpretedRuntime.parse(MVELInterpretedRuntime.java:49)
    at org.mvel2.MVEL.eval(MVEL.java:408)
    at org.mvel2.ast.IfNode.getReducedValue(IfNode.java:89)
    at org.mvel2.MVELInterpretedRuntime.parseAndExecuteInterpreted(MVELInterpretedRuntime.java:106)
    at org.mvel2.MVELInterpretedRuntime.parse(MVELInterpretedRuntime.java:49)
    at org.mvel2.MVEL.eval(MVEL.java:165)
    at com.nucleus.rules.service.MvelTest.main(MvelTest.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.nodes.NullSafe$1.getValue(NullSafe.java:39)
    at org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.nodes.NullSafe.getValue(NullSafe.java:54)
    at org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.nodes.GetterAccessor.getValue(GetterAccessor.java:40)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: The exception is odd in that does not seem to reference what I would think it would, but you are doing `loopVariable0.?child.?age` which would be invoked even if the child is null which would cause that NPE.

Comment: @MikeKobit yes but somehow it hold first element in some node and compares, might be. since adding null object on 2nd index inside list, does not cause any issue, even if first element does not meet criteria, 3rd element gets executed.

Comment: Can you please tell Mvel version no.

Answer (score 0):

Its work for me in version 2.0. I have tried even null in 2 or 3 position its throwing exception

I have attached exception

```
    Exception in thread "main" [Error: cannot invoke getter: getChild [declr.class: Student; act.class: Student]]
[Near : {... ame ;}}} else { return "Noo" } ....}]
[Line: 1, Column: 218]
    at org.mvel.MVELInterpretedRuntime.parseAndExecuteInterpreted(MVELInterpretedRuntime.java:156)
    at org.mvel.MVELInterpretedRuntime.parse(MVELInterpretedRuntime.java:54)
    at org.mvel.MVEL.eval(MVEL.java:124)
    at MvelTest.main(MvelTest.java:33)
Caused by: [Error: cannot invoke getter: getChild [declr.class: Student; act.class: Student]]
[Near : {... loopVariable0.?child.?name ;} ....}]
[Line: 1, Column: 143]
    at org.mvel.MVELInterpretedRuntime.parseAndExecuteInterpreted(MVELInterpretedRuntime.java:156)
    at org.mvel.MVELInterpretedRuntime.parse(MVELInterpretedRuntime.java:54)
    at org.mvel.MVEL.eval(MVEL.java:107)
    at org.mvel.ast.IfNode.getReducedValue(IfNode.java:64)
    at org.mvel.MVELInterpretedRuntime.parseAndExecuteInterpreted(MVELInterpretedRuntime.java:106)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: [Error: cannot invoke getter: getChild [declr.class: Student; act.class: Student]]
[Near : {... Unknown ....}]
    at org.mvel.optimizers.impl.refl.GetterAccessor.getValue(GetterAccessor.java:51)
    at org.mvel.optimizers.impl.refl.VariableAccessor.getValue(VariableAccessor.java:38)
    at org.mvel.optimizers.dynamic.DynamicGetAccessor.getValue(DynamicGetAccessor.java:44)
    at org.mvel.ast.ASTNode.getReducedValueAccelerated(ASTNode.java:97)
    at org.mvel.ast.BinaryOperation.getReducedValueAccelerated(BinaryOperation.java:64)
    at org.mvel.compiler.ExecutableAccessor.getValue(ExecutableAccessor.java:46)
    at org.mvel.ast.IfNode.getReducedValueAccelerated(IfNode.java:48)
    at org.mvel.compiler.ExecutableAccessor.getValue(ExecutableAccessor.java:46)
    at org.mvel.ast.ForEachNode.getReducedValue(ForEachNode.java:148)
    at org.mvel.MVELInterpretedRuntime.parseAndExecuteInterpreted(MVELInterpretedRuntime.java:106)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: [Error: cannot invoke getter: getAge [declr.class: Child; act.class: null]]
[Near : {... Unknown ....}]
    at org.mvel.optimizers.impl.refl.GetterAccessor.getValue(GetterAccessor.java:51)
    at org.mvel.optimizers.impl.refl.GetterAccessor.getValue(GetterAccessor.java:38)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.mvel.optimizers.impl.refl.GetterAccessor.getValue(GetterAccessor.java:41)
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: i am using `2.2.0.Final`

Comment: @Mike Brock need your comments, if a bug in MVEL, how can i report.

Comment: @tobias_k need your comments, if a bug in MVEL, how can i report.

Comment: @Florent Guillaume need your comments, if a bug in MVEL, how can i report.

Comment: @ankur-singhal Pl try 2.0 . Its Mvel bug.

Comment: you are getting as well the same issue with object as null on any index, correct..??

Comment: then switching to previous version will not help me either correct,?? also how can we report a bug to MVEL.

Comment: @ankur-singhal I have tried in 2.0 its working for me. May be they have introduced some new feature it only you are going to miss

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66705/discussion-between-ankur-singhal-and-siva-kumar).